# Gatling Stress test of websockets with different users

Tags: gatling

This is my sample test case in scala for gatling

```
 val baseurl = s"http://$server:$port/$cPath"
  val wsurl = s"ws://$server:$port/$cPath"

  val httpProtocol = http
  .baseURL(baseurl)
  .inferHtmlResources(BlackList(""".*\.js""", """.*\.css""", """.*\.gif""", """.*\.jpeg""", """.*\.jpg""", """.*\.ico""", """.*\.woff""", """.*\.(t|o)tf""", """.*\.png"""), WhiteList())
  .acceptHeader("""*/*""")
  .acceptEncodingHeader("""gzip,deflate,sdch""")
  .acceptLanguageHeader("""en-US,en;q=0.8,fi;q=0.6""")
  .contentTypeHeader("""application/json; charset=UTF-8""")
  .userAgentHeader("""Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36""")
  .wsBaseURL(wsurl)

    val scn = scenario("wsloadtest").group("Create Process"){exec(ws("connect")
      .open(wsurl))
      .exec(
      ws("Suggest answer 3")
      .sendText("""{"messageType":"loginMessage","channel":"3","userId":"10","timestamp":"1458459904939"}""")).pause(21474800)

  };

  //val sample = scenario("socket").exec()
  setUp(scn.inject(
    //heavisideUsers(40000) over(500)
    constantUsersPerSec(50) during(400)
    )).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

Through the above test i am able to send same userId in json is there a possibility to simulate login of different users(UserId is a long value and it should be be dynamic..If yes how can this be done..Sorry if framing of the question is not clear..

Comment: Am I misunderstanding the question, or can you just modify the `"userId":"10"` part to a different number?

Comment: @Vulcan But how can i declare as variable..for example..i have check various other esxamples like https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/master/gatling-http/src/test/scala/io/gatling/http/WsCompileTest.scala..In this example...$id is variable and which has the value of session.userId..But session.userId is not a Numeric value(79471971958111694-353) this is one of the sample values i got..the userId should be long value type in java..hope its clear?

Comment: This is the link  https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/master/gatling-http/src/test/scala/io/gatling/http/WsCompileTest.scala